# WebScrape field with multiple same tags

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My code navigates into a webpage successfully, I want to scrape all data under the "*description*" field for rows that contain this field.

So far, my code prints all the tags of this *description* field, which also includes multiple other fields as they contain the same tag/className. It also looks like some text in the description field is cut off?

I just want a list of all description text, for applicable rows.

(You can see a demo execution if you run my code)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.kidney.org/spring-clinical/program')
time.sleep(4)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
frame= WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.NAME, "SCM20 Advanced Practitioner Program")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
options = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="track-selector-popup"] [role="option"]')))

options[0].click()
page_source = driver.page_source
time.sleep(2)

description=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ng-binding']")
for i in description:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: It's hard to see without corresponding HTML

Comment: Did my solution resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you identified correctly, the class tag 'ng-binding' is used multiple times, not only for the *Description* blocks. However, you can retrieve only the description text by providing the correct xpath:

```
description = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='desc spacing ng-scope']/div/span/span/span[@class='ng-binding']")
```

The text is cut off because you need to click on *more* first to expand the whole description. This can be achieved by finding all elements with a clickable link that says *more*, for instance, and then clicking each link found in a for loop. This code chunk needs to go before the collection of description texts.

```
more_links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("more")
for element in more_links:
    element.click()
```

This is the complete code that navigates to the *Advanced Practitioner Program* and retrieves all complete descriptions of the events:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://www.kidney.org/spring-clinical/program')
time.sleep(4)

adv_prac_prog =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Advanced Practitioner Program')]")))
adv_prac_prog.click()

more_links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("more")
for element in more_links:
    element.click()

description = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='desc spacing ng-scope']/div/span/span/span[@class='ng-binding']")
for i in description:
    print("\n")
    print(i.text)
    print("\n")
```

Comment: The xpath needed to be specified properly and the description texts had to be expanded before text retrieval. Does this solution work for you?